# Android : How to use VLC without exiting current Activity ? (For background audio)

Tags: android, android-intent, vlc, rtsp, vlc-android

Presumed : VLC for Android is installed on device and works fine.

Actually I can start VLC with my URL and listen an audio stream with real-time capabilities ( < 1 sec ) with that :

```
 private void startRTSPStreamOnVLC(String ip, String port, String path) {
    final String url = "rtsp://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + path;

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc");
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/h264");
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.videolan.vlc", "org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Problem is, it brings VLC on the screen, causing my application to Pause/Stop and breaks my other way audio stream.

It would be even greater if I could open VLC in a View I could show in my Layout actually.

I know of Services to be used as Activity without GUI, but It would implies changing VLC itself, which I really wish to avoid.

Any secret tip to achieve that ?

-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-'-

EDIT / Answer :
As Vikash Kumar Verma said, using LibVLC was the way to go.
I had to compile it for my ABI (mips) by following [this guide.](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/)
The most recent example of app I found was [this one.](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample)

Managed to go down to 550ms delay of my RTSP audio stream running on Windows 7 with VLC as server. I had to go in the Media class and changed line 771 like following :

```
 addOption(":network-caching=0"); // Was 1500
```

Comment: `StartActivity` will allways show new activity. The only way say VLC to play some audio - send broadcast to it. But I don't know what `Intent` should be inside - you can google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use VLC in your your layout. Have a look at  [MyVlcPlayer](https://github.com/vkdinventor/MyVlcPlayer). I have use libVLC library to play video in my application.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the right direction. Still your project uses a 3 years outdated LibVlc, I will edit my post to explain more about what I find.

Comment: hehe  :)  @J.Jacobs-VP I hope I one day I will find time to update to new LibVlc